# Prettier [error] No files matching the pattern were found: "src\app\app.component.html"

Tags: angular, webstorm, prettier

I have setup an Angular 10 application. Here are the steps I have used:

1. Installed Prettier as global
2. Added `.prettierrc` file
3. I was trying to setup a file watcher with the below configuration

[image]

4. But it is not detecting any file changes and throwing the below error

[image]

Interesting thing is exactly the same setup is working in Angular 9. Really weird.

```
WebStorm 2020.2
Build #WS-202.6397.88, built on July 25, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.7+10-b944.20 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1979M
Cores: 16
Registry: ide.intellij.laf.enable.animation=true, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI, com.mallowigi, com.mallowigi.idea, com.markskelton.one-dark-theme, github.cweijan.test-theme
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what working directory is configured in watcher settings? And, BTW, why do you need Prettier file watcher? In 2020.2, you can set up Prettier to run on *Save* right in Prettier preferences, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.2/prettier.html#ws_prettier_run_automatically_in_current_project

Comment: Thanks @lena. Given link is clear and works really well.

Answer (score 0):

The `Program` value is looking to find the `prettier runner` in your local project not globally, So install the Prettier's runner locally

```sh
npm i --save-dev prettier
```